# How to fix the length of a IntegerField, or AutoField?

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my serial (working like the id), has exactly 13 characters, there is some atribute for this?
Example: Instead of 3, I need the serial become a INTEGER of 0000000000003.

```
class Entrada(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    medicamento = models.ForeignKey(Medicamento, verbose_name=_(u'Medicamento'))
    serial = models.AutoField(_(u'Serial'), null=False, blank=False, unique=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
    validade = models.DateField(_(u'Validade'), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    lote = models.CharField(_(u'Lote do fabricante'), null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)
    quantidade = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Quantidade'), null=False)
    mud = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Menor unidade de dispensa'), null=False)
    data_entrada = models.DateField(_(u'Data de entrada'), default=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .zfill to put leading zeros in your integer:

```
str(3).zfill(13)
```

That will give you a string. You can cast it later as an integer with int().

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the maximum value an AutoField can hold is 2147483647.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.10 will add support for a [BigAutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield). You can try to copy their implementation by looking at its [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#BigAutoField).